# Web Components: attributeChangedCallback() function not triggered even after mentioning the observedAttributed()

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-component

I have created a Web Component which has 2 inputs: `btnText` and `btnDisabled`. I have mentioned these 2 attributed in the `static get observedAttributes() {}`. Yet, the `attributeChangedCallback()` does not get triggered. Below is my Web Component:

```
// import sheet from './button.css' assert { type: 'css' };

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion */
export class ButtonElement extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['btnText', 'btnDisabled'];
  }

  get btnText() {
    return this.getAttribute('btnText')?.trim() || 'Next';
  }

  set btnText(value: string) {
    console.log('Setting button text value...', value);
    this.setAttribute('btnText', value);
    this.render();
  }

  get btnDisabled() {
    return Boolean(this.getAttribute('btnState'));
  }

  set btnDisabled(value: boolean) {
    console.log('Setting button state value...', value);
    if (value) {
      this.setAttribute('btnState', value.toString());
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute('btnState');
    }
    this.render();
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    // super.connectedCallback();
    // this.renderRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];

    console.log('Element added to the DOM');

    this.setAllAttributes();

    /* This method renders the button */
    this.render();
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    console.log('Element removed from the DOM');
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(
    attributeName: string,
    oldValue: string,
    newValue: string
  ) {
    console.log(
      `Attribute ${attributeName} changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.shadowRoot) return;

    console.log('My button text is ', this.btnText);

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }

        :host-context([btnState='true']) button {
          background-color: var(--button-disabled-color);
          border-color: var(--button-disabled-border-color);
          color: var(--color-disabled);
          cursor: not-allowed;
        }

        button {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          place-items: center;
          outline: none;
          background-color: var(--button-primary-color);
          border: 1px solid transparent;
          border-color: var(--button-primary-border-color);
          color: var(--color-primary);
          user-select: none;
          font-size: 1.1rem;
          padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
          border-radius: var(--button-border-radius, var(--button-default-border-radius));
          cursor: pointer;
          height: 50px;
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
      <button>
        <slot name="left-icon"></slot>
        <slot>${this.btnText}</slot>
        <slot name="right-icon"></slot>
      </button>
    `;

    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  private setAllAttributes() {
    this.btnText = this.getAttribute('btnText') || this.btnText;
  }

  private addEventListeners() {
    console.log('Adding event listeners...');
    const btn = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('button');
    console.log('$$$$ ', btn);

    btn?.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('Button is clicked inside the custom element...');

    /* Dispatching a custom event */
    const eventData = { theme: document.documentElement.getAttribute('theme') };
    const event = new CustomEvent('buttonClicked', {
      detail: eventData,
      bubbles: true,
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}

customElements.define('ag-button', ButtonElement);
```

Upon entering text in the text box and checking disabled checkbox, I am expecting the attributeChangedCalleback() to be triggered.

I tried mentioning the attributes in `observedAttributes()` using camel case and kebab case. Both of them didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes in the HTML namespace are lower case, so you need to define them as such in the `observedAttributes`.

```js
class ButtonElement extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["btntext"]; // lower case
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(
    attributeName,
    oldValue,
    newValue
  ) {
    console.log(
      `Attribute ${attributeName} changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`
    );
  }
}
customElements.define('ag-button', ButtonElement);
document.querySelector("ag-button").setAttribute("btnText", "bar");
```

```html
<ag-button btnText="foo"></ag-button>
```

(You *can* have cased attributes on HTML elements, but you need to use a non HTML document to create these:

```js
class ButtonElement extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["btnText"];
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(
    attributeName,
    oldValue,
    newValue
  ) {
    console.log(
      `Attribute ${attributeName} changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`
    );
  }
}
customElements.define('ag-button', ButtonElement);
const svgDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
const attr = svgDoc.createAttribute("btnText");
attr.value = "bar";
document.querySelector("ag-button").attributes.setNamedItem(attr);
```

```html
<!-- The HTML parser will fail to set it correctly -->
<ag-button btnText="foo"></ag-button>
```

)

Though the standard way to define multi-word attributes is to use kebab-case, but you need to use it in both the markup and in your class definition:

```js
class ButtonElement extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["btn-text"];
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(
    attributeName,
    oldValue,
    newValue
  ) {
    console.log(
      `Attribute ${attributeName} changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`
    );
  }
}
customElements.define('ag-button', ButtonElement);
document.querySelector("ag-button").setAttribute("btn-text", "bar");
```

```html
<ag-button btn-text="foo"></ag-button>
```